# Cartoon TV show with a group of dinosaurs

Tags: story-identification, cartoon, dinosaurs

I have this memory of a TV cartoon show with a bunch of dinosaurs (5, I guess), each with different colors and from different species. One was a triceratops, another was a diplodocus, but they were all the same size. They were really cartoonish.

There were no humans, and the stories happened way before our time, hence they were discovering many things.

I remember seeing that show as a child in France, so between 1995 and 2005.

One of the episodes I remember is when they see a rainbow for the first time and they decide to build a raft to see its beginning. The whole episode was them rowing, imagining what it could be and giving it a name. They argue between "Rainbow" ("Arc-en-ciel" in French) and "Color Acre" ("Arpent à couleurs" in French, not sure at all for English). Finally, they understand that they'll never get the rainbow and go back where they came from.

Of course, this is NOT *The Land Before Time*, neither *Denver*.

Comment: I'd have said [Dink the dinosaur](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pN2ahsmNq4w) but there's no triceratops and I can't seem to find any rainbow episode. [The Diplodos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2GQyk0SYC64) might have been able to build a raft, because they had, hands, but there are humans on this show.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Okay, I think I found it. The design definitely rings a bell, the dates are good, and even if I can't find the rainbow episode, I know it's this one.

[image: Dino Babies]

It's *Dino Babies* (*Dino Junior* in french), a cartoon produced in 1993 and broadcast in 1997 in France. On wikipedia.fr, I see Ireland for the origin country, but on .en it's Canada/UK. Anyways, it's the story of six dinosaurs that tell themselves classical tales (the emperor's new robes, sleeping beauty...) with their own imaginative spin.

There was a triceratops, but not one of the main characters - a recurrent one at least.

I found it when I clicked on the link for Dink in one of the answers and saw other suggestions.

Answer (score 5):

I know you said it's not [*The Land Before Time*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Land_Before_Time_(TV_series)), but it did have a TV series and episode 24, "Search for the Sky Color Stones" involved a rainbow:

> When the gang sees the sky colors in the sky disappear (a rainbow), the gang splits up to find sky color stones (geodes).

The group does include a triceratops (Cera). I don't believe there was a Diplodocus featured in the TV series (although the film had "Doc"), but Littlefoot has variously been identified as a Brontosaurus, a Brachiosaurus, and an Apatosaurus as science marched on.

[image: Land Before Time Cast - Fanart]

Comment: No, that definitely can't be that. The land before time is one of my favorite film ever, I'd remember. Plus, the design was way more cartoonish.

Comment: So, more crude animation? Less realistic dinosaur anatomy?